# Is there a support for c++11 in netbeans ide 7.1.1

Tags: c++, multithreading, netbeans, scheduler

I need to ask is there support for c++11 (making use of libaries as thread,chrono) in netbeans 7.1.1 .

I had this code :-

```
#include<thread>
#include<chrono>
while(true)
{
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));   <- there is an error at 
"this_thread" 

test4();
}
```

actually i am working on making something that calls this function after every minute(by this i mean when the system time changes by a minute )

thanks

Comment: What compiler are you using? if g++, it supports most of the C++11 features in its 4.7 release.

Comment: netbeans is an **ide** not a compiler.

Comment: @the compiler is g++ and the ide is 7.1.1

Comment: @then why does it gives me an error as std::this_error is not declared,std::chrono has not been declared

Comment: That code isn't valid. `while` needs to be inside a function block.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to ask whether you compiler supports C++11, not your IDE.

Well, for g++, it supports most of c++11 features in its 4.7 release.

Comment: :-isnt it like the ide that has provided the compiler makes changes every realease , can u please suggest why it shows me an error then

Comment: This answer is not 100% correct imho. Many IDE's provide things like auto-completion, member resolving or even very basic static analyzers that can very well fail when using new C++11 code. For example, When using gcc's standard library, all C++11 new classes/functions are behind a preprocessor flag and may not be recognized by the IDE, resulting in "IDE errors" (it will compile but reduce your IDE's usefulness).

Answer (score 5):

Three things (Compiler, IDE and OS) are ALL important here.

1) Compiler: GCC 4.6 already has good C++11 support and has the `<thread>` and `<chrono>` headers. But you must compile with `-std=c++0x`. If you use an IDE, it must be configured to generate makes as such (so check the compiler option)

2) OS is also important: The `<thread>` header is essentially a set of wrappers around the POSIX concept of ptherad, mutex and condition_variable. On Windows, condition_variable are natively present only from 0x600 (Vista), Up to 0x505 (XP) you have to deal with the native "synchronization EVENT objects", which can be equivalent, bu have different semantics (`boost::thread` implements adaptors, but GCC **just skips the entire thread implementation**: hence... if you are writing for more OSes, check if you are using a library implementation that exist on all of them!)

3) The IDE also has its importance: the way the editors parse the text and display completion information, as well as "syntax error while typing" etc. doen NOT depend on the compiler but on the parser they use.
In particular, GCC when configured with -std=c++0X, it assumes the implicit definition of the `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__` symbol, that is not automatically assumed by the IDE (that parses the headers wrongly)
You have so also to configure the IDE to consider the `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__` symbol as "defined" while parsing.

Your problem is most likely related to point 3